# What HTML, when copied from browser and pasted into Word, will give a tab character?

Tags: html, ms-word

Word does a fairly faithful job of interpreting HTML when it's pasted in. It can recognise all sorts of style features (indents, fonts, colors, etc). I want to construct some HTML that, when viewed in a browser and pasted into word, will include a tab character.

What I've tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
  <head>
    <title>HTML Paste Into Word Giving Tab</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>With span containing<span style='mso-tab-count:1'>��� </span>weird characters.</p>
    <p>With span containing<span style='mso-tab-count:1'> </span>a space.</p>
    <p>With span containing<span style='mso-tab-count:1'>&#09;</span>&amp;#09.</p>
    <p>With span containing<span style='mso-tab-count:1'></span>nothing.</p>
    <p>Just a&#09;&amp;#09</p>
    <ol start="3."><li>using OL and LI tags</li></ol>
    <ol start="First part"><li>and second part using OL/LI</li></ol>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

When I view the above HTML in a browser, and paste into word, the result is as shown below.

When I save a word document that contains tabs as HTML, the html contains things like `<span style='mso-tab-count:1'>��� </span>`. Each of those weird characters in hex is EF BF BD.

If I paste that same code into my HTML, open in a browser, and paste into word, I get three weird characters followed by a non-breaking space. If I substitute anything else for the weird characters, I get a non-breaking space. An empty span seems to be ignored. A &#09 symbol turns into a regular space.

You can see that Word did generate a tab in the OL/LI case. But there are limits to what I can put in the start attribute: if I put arbitrary text in there, it won't render properly.

I'd like to be able to have some arbitrary text, followed by a tab symbol, followed by more text, when my HTML is copied and pasted into Word.

I'm using Chrome 87 and Word from Office 365 (16.0.13328.20334).

[image]

Comment: I would humbly suggest that you're chasing a unicorn. The tab character is represented by 4 space characters but multiple spaces collapse into 1 space on web pages. So you're rarely going to find a tab character on a web page. As an equivalent, take a look at the &emsp; character, which creates 4 spaces in a row.

Comment: @JohnKorchok I think you may be right. If someone helps me find it, does that mean it wasn't actually a unicorn, or that I'm really lucky? I'm hoping to do some tab-based alignment using variable width fonts, without introducing another level of tables into my document. So &nbsp; or &emsp; won't really help there. But I wasn't aware of &emsp; so thanks!

Comment: This may not be useful information, but I copy a lot of recipes and I notice that many of them have 4-space leaders on ordered lists when pasted as text into Word. That's probably a similar circumstance under which you would be wanting to create a tab. You'll probably have to create a macro or use some other programmatic solution to translate to tabs in Word.